# Adding one line in sudoku checker break my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

```
function validSolution(board){
  for(i=0;i<board.length;i++){
    if (new Set(board[i]).size != 9) return false
    //if (new Set(getVertical(i,board)).size != 9) return false
  }
  return true
}
let getVertical = (num,board) => {
  let result = []
  for(i=0;i<board.length;i++){
    result.push(board[i][num])
  }
  console.log(result)
  return result
}
```

I am working on sudoku checker if I am adding the commented line of code the tests that were passing are failing :( like the first 'if' statement disappeared

sample input (should be false) and it is until adding second 'if' statement

```
[[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
[6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 8],
[1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
[8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
[4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
[7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
[9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
[2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
[3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: After you call `getVertical`, `i===9`and the loop is over

Comment: why ? how i can fix that ?

Comment: By declaring your variables *(where you use them)* and not letting both loops share the same implicitely declared global variable. In your code, both loops use the same variable. Not just the same name for a variable, but the very same global variable.

Answer (score -1):

The propblem is that you declare variable `i` without `let` keyword.
That means `i` is a **global** variable, so in getVertical function `i` store value `8` and main loop in `validSolution` skip to end and returns `true`